# Colunas de Tabelas diferentes num Where

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Comecei a estudar MySQL recentemente e estou com um problema com o meu código.
Basicamente, estou fazendo um sistema para bibliotecas e quero fazer um trigger para definir o status de um determinado livro como "Emprestado" quando um usuário realizar o empréstimo do livro.

Tenho a tabela Livro com 'idl' como chave primária, conforme o código indica:

```
create table livro(
    idl int not null auto_increment,
    nome varchar(50) not null,
    autor varchar(100) not null,
    genero varchar(50) not null,
    editora varchar(50) not null,
    status varchar(10) not null default 'Disponível',
    primary key(idl)
);
```

E tenho a tabela de empréstimo que usa o 'idl' como chave estrangeira pra associação com determinado livro:

```
create table emprestimo(
    ide int not null auto_increment,
    nomeC varchar(100) not null,
    fone varchar(15) not null,
    idl int not null,
    primary key(ide),
    constraint fk_livro foreign key(idl) references livro(idl)
);
```

Quero fazer um trigger que mude o status de um livro para "Emprestado" sempre que eu realizar um empréstimo com o id associado dele. Tentei o seguinte código:

```
delimiter $
    create trigger tgr_emprestimo_insert after insert
on emprestimo
for each row
begin
    update livro set status = 'Emprestado'
    where livro.idl=emprestimo.idl;
end$
```

Porém ao tentar executar o código eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 41: Unknown column 'emprestimo.idl' in 'where clause'

Inicialmente pensei que poderia ser algum erro de formatação anterior, mas quando substitui 'emprestimo.idl' por qualquer valor numérico, o código rodou sem problemas. Alguém pode me explicar o que eu poderia fazer pra isso funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode pegar o registro da tabela "emprestimo" com uma *subquery*, e usar a função `LAST_INSERT_ID()` para pegar o id do último registro adicionado naquela tabela, assim por exemplo:

```
update livro set status = 'Emprestado'
 where livro.idl = (select idl 
                      from emprestimo
                     where ide = LAST_INSERT_ID())`
```

Aqui [mais informação sobre a função `LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)